# Should I pull from the server or just update the view?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using Ajax on a website, I make changes to the data through the view. I send this data to the server so it's saved. My steps are outlined below:

1. User changes data on the view.
2. Javascript triggers.
3. *Before ajax call*
4. Ajax call. Server saves data.
5. *After ajax call*

My question is: Is it better, design-wise, to update the view in step three and then update the data and just let the data be potentially out of sync until a refresh or to make the ajax call, then return the data from the server and update the view with that in step five?

I currently have the first option implemented since it was a little easier and just "flowed" for me better, but the second one seems better, since the user will always get up-to-date data from the server.

Comment: Depends on what kind of changes you're making server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **Availability** vs **Consistency**. It depends on you whether you want to be more available or consistent. What happens if something goes wrong and the information couldn't be updated in server side, do your users get angry? Or maybe your users get angry if they cannot see the right value of the content? You have to decide one or another. This is article about this situation [Consistency vs. availability: eventual consistency by Werner Vogels](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/01/consistency-vs-availability)

Comment: Thanks! I found a better way to display that the server was updating to the user. I guess this is a pretty common question everybody asks themselves eventually.

Answer (score 0):

IMO update the data in step 3, but show some notice saying "saving data to server" or just a loading gif. then make the ajax call and have it return status of operation (OK if data was saved correctly, Error otherwise), read the response and hide the saving data div or pull data from server in case of error.

this way user won't have to wait for ajax call or a refresh. it will flow better and you can handle errors efficiently